# How to test a long running Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, server

I am working on a Multi-player game for my final year project and currently working on the Server area. In the Server I am working on the movement area which works as follows

Player makes a Movement **->** A packet is sent to Server with details of movement **->** The server queues the movement in a queue which is contained inside the player object **->** The server keeps looping through all the players connected **->** Server checks for movementqueue of player -> Server updates the position of player **->** Server sends the movement details to other clients.

So to achieve this I will have Runnables called MovementService which will have queues of players distributed amongst themselves. The number of runnable depends on the resources as queueing up every player on one thread means a lot of lag, So there will be at least 4 runnables or one can say 4 long running Threads. These runnables will be added to a FixedThreadPool.

Now my problem is how will I test this implementation as this is a long running thread and I am not sure how will I go about testing it as I have posted a similar question earlier but the answer suggested me to change my entire design.
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426494/how-to-unit-test-thread-which-takes-time-to-perform-action) is the question. The approach given in the answer cannot be implemented here because I cannot keep submitting short runnables for every movement packet received on the server to a ThreadPool.

My question is how should I go about testing this Runnable implementation. Is there any other or better way to do it?

Here is the relevant code from my Movement Service

```
public class DefaultMovementService implements MovementService{

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){
            synchronized (playerQueue) {
                playerQueue.forEach(player -> move(player));
            }
        }
    }

    private void move(Player player) {
        //If player tank has movement, move the tank.
        //Send the movement to the other clients on the same map
    }
}
```

`MovementService` interface extends `Runnable`.

Comment: I think the right way is you don't test `Runnable`, it already works.  You test `playerQueue`, in a test harness, outside of the runnable.

Comment: Where do you ever pop anything from playerQueue?

Comment: When a player logs out, I have a method in the service void removePlayer(Player player). This does the job. I haven't included it in my code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a mocking framework (EasyMock) to create a mock of playerQueue and add expectations of what should be called.
Next thing:

```
   @Override
    public void run() {
        while(isRunning){
            synchronized (playerQueue) {
                playerQueue.forEach(player -> move(player));
            }
        }
    }
```

This `while running` is very error prone approach for this task.
Create a scheduled thread pool and submit this task to run at some fixed rate (10 milliseconds for instance) and remove the while(isRunning); You can cancel the scheduled task by calling `ScheduledFutute<?> future.cancel(false);`

Comment: Yeah I do use a mocking framework and I did use the technique you have specified in the linked question but the problem is I cannot do that here. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33426494/how-to-unit-test-thread-which-takes-time-to-perform-action?lq=1
Also I am not sure how scheduled pool will work here.

Comment: Well you just have to make your code more testable either by design or implementation. This is a very common problem in the programming world, developers tend to not think about the testability of their code but a moment comes where they are unable to be sure that their code is even working. Think about it and you will benefit in long terms.

Comment: That's why I asked the question, I can just use this implementation as I know it will work but for the long run I want to properly test it and hence looking for a better implementation :) @Zpetkov